# Regex for currency code and amount coming in any order

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching, currency

I would like to capture an ISO [currency code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) (i.e. USD or EUR) and amount (i.e. 2 or 5.34) appearing in any order. For example, the regex should capture these strings: `from USD 24.5 and less` or `25 EUR`

Comment: Anything that looks like currency code or exactly from the list of currency codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do what you want:

```
/(?:[A-Z]{3} [0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)? [A-Z]{3})/
```

- The iso currency code can be before or after the amount
- The amount can contain a decimal value, or not